# how to know if updateChildren() on Firebase Realtime database was successful or not?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am incrementing multiple nodes' value using ServerValue.increment() method

In below DB I want to increment Wallet/uID/bal value for multiple UIDs:

[image: Firebase db]

**OnComplete callback always runs**, but it doesn't always increments balance.
I want to retry if values were not incremented, how can I know if values were incremented or not and how to retry?

**Below is the code:**

```
Map<String, Object> children = new HashMap<>();
children.put("Wallet" + "/" + UID1+"/bal", ServerValue.increment(10));
children.put("Wallet" + "/" + UID2+"/bal", ServerValue.increment(10));
children.put("Wallet" + "/" + UID3+"/bal", ServerValue.increment(10));
//and so on
        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().updateChildren(children, new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@Nullable DatabaseError error, @NonNull DatabaseReference ref) {
              // how to know here? if successful or any error?
            }
        });
```

Comment: Do the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#add_a_completion_callback) help you? You can add listeners for success and failure cases.

Comment: b2m9 thanks for your comment, it has onComplete listener only and its running all time time  https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#atomic_server-side_increments

Comment: Because onComplete runs when the request is finished - no matter whether it was a success or not. Hence the first argument `DatabaseError` - check it. [It is null on success](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference.CompletionListener#parameters)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I just noticed it , docs says ," If it has succeeded, the error will be null" thanks a lot.

Comment: So you want to know if all operations are complete or fail, or do you need to know for each one of them? Please respond with @AlexMamo

Comment: @AlexMamo I wanted to know if all of them complete atomically or not. Thanks for your comment. 

Comment: In that case, Frank's answer solves the problem ;)

Answer (score 0):

All operations in a single call to `updateChildren` either succeed or they all fail.

If they fail on the server, the `error` parameter of your `onComplete` handler will indicate why it failed; typically that'll be related to the security rules of your database.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try to check if the error is null or not? If the error is null, it's successful. Else fail. Try this code:

```java
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().updateChildren(children, new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@Nullable DatabaseError error, @NonNull DatabaseReference ref) {
              if(error == null && ref != null){ 
                 // there was no error and the value is modified
              }
              else{
                 // there was an error. try to update again
              }
            }
        });
```